# IIS 8 Error when Installing Octopus Deploy Server on Windows Server 2012

Tags: continuous-integration, octopus-deploy

I wonder if anyone has encountered the above issue: 
I was able to install the server successfully but when it comes to run the utility that configures the octopus settings, I get the following error

> One or more windows features need to be enabled before continuing.

and then I get  this afterwards:

> "DISM.exe /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:IIS-ASPNET
>   /FeatureName:IIS-NetFxExtensibility /ALL"

In order to enable the missing feature.
This has now been done successfully. But everytime i try to run Octopus deploy administrative tool I keeping getting the same error.

Is there something I'm missing regarding components I need to have on to the 2012 windows server.

Answer (score 1):

I have never encountered the errors you are mentioning. That said, have you performed a full GUI install of Octopus Deploy, or just the server core? To make it work properly on Windows Server 2012 you need to do a full GUI install.

Answer (score 1):

This must be quite an old version of Octopus - only the 1.x versions required IIS to install the Octopus server (and I don't think it supported Server Core).

The 2.x and 3.x versions don't use IIS (we are a self-hosted NancyFX service).